# Interpolation error with gsl akima spline

Tags: c, interpolation, gsl

I'm getting a 'gsl: interp.c:150: ERROR: interpolation error' with the following code. Some googling says that this error occurs when you try to extrapolate using the interp function but I don't see how that is happening here. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

The function `randomground()` just returns a random number (double).

```
#define NSTEPS 100   

int main()
{
           int j, q, space = 1, refine = 100;
           double xi = 0.0, tx[2*NSTEPS] = {0}, theight[2*NSTEPS] = {0};

           double terrain[(int) (2*NSTEPS*100)] = {0};
           double terrainsl[(int) (2*NSTEPS*100)] = {0};

            for (j = 0; j < 2*NSTEPS; j++)
            {
                tx[j] = (double) j*space;
                theight[j] = randomground();
            }

            gsl_interp_accel *acc = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
            gsl_spline *spline = gsl_spline_alloc(gsl_interp_akima, 2*NSTEPS);
            gsl_spline_init(spline, tx, theight, 2*NSTEPS);

            for (q = 0; q< 2*NSTEPS*100; q++)
            {
                terrain[q] = gsl_spline_eval(spline,xi,acc);
                terrainsl[q] = gsl_spline_eval_deriv(spline,xi,acc);
                xi = xi+(double) space/refine;
            }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should add that when I run this on my Windows machine there is no error but when I run it on the Linux server in the lab, I get the interp error

Comment: Float precision error may be the problem. Add a small shift to tx's first and last elements to increase the range. This won't affect your final result because the required precision in your calculation is probably much lower than double precision.

Comment: @ViniciusMiranda, sorry I don't get what you mean by 'Add a small shift to tx's first and last elements'

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by adding an extra element to tx and theight. I'm guessing this is what you had asked me to do, @ViniciusMiranda. The code now reads

```
                double tx[2*NSTEPS+1] = {0}, theight[2*NSTEPS+1] = {0};
                double terrain[(int) (2*NSTEPS*100)] = {0};
                double terrainsl[(int) (2*NSTEPS*100)] = {0};

            for (j = 0; j < 2*NSTEPS+1; j++)
            {
                tx[j] = (double) j*space;
                theight[j] = randomground();
            }

            gsl_interp_accel *acc = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
            gsl_spline *spline = gsl_spline_alloc(gsl_interp_akima, 2*NSTEPS+1);
            gsl_spline_init(spline, tx, theight, 2*NSTEPS+1);

            for (q = 0; q< 2*NSTEPS*100; q++)
            {
                terrain[q] = gsl_spline_eval(spline,xi,acc);
                terrainsl[q] = gsl_spline_eval_deriv(spline,xi,acc);
                xi = xi+(double) space/refine;
            }
```

I still don't understand why this fix was required though.

Comment: The source of the problem is that you asked the interpolation to provide you the height at the boundary but float number errors ( 0.0 == 0.0 is usually false because of truncation in the 16th digit for doubles!) can give you extrapolation errors. That is why I proposed you to increase the range. The first element in array is 0 and you start asking the interpolation at zero. One fast hack to test the presence of this error is to add a small shift at the boundaries tx[0] = 0 - 1e-14 and tx[size-1] = last_element*(1+1e-14).

Answer (score 0):

Akima spline is a local, sub-spline interpolation. For a function `f(x)`, if you are trying to obtain the value of `x` for `x_i <= x <= x_i+1`, Akima spline needs the pairs `(x_j, f_j)` for `j = i-2, i-1, i, i+1, i+2, i+3.`

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error in my code `zigzag.sourceforge.net`  and resolved by commenting the line in the `gsl library source`, compiling it and reinstalling.

> Before version 1.14 there is in interp.c the line 150

```
// GSL_ERROR_VAL("interpolation error", GSL_EDOM, GSL_NAN);
```

that I comment to solve the break !